# Left join table null value replace with right table column

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I need to sum of task completed by employee between given date range (Here I am using 1 month 1-Jan to 31-Jan 2017)

[This is a table where every employee daily completed number of task recorded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSYs2.png)

I have master table emp_task ( right join table)  as shown in the below image

And created date range table dat_calender (left join table) using below query as shown in the image
[This is temporary table used to create date range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjDzt.png)

I join the both above table using below query

```
select nam_emp,dat_day,sum(num_task) from dat_calender
       left join emp_task
       on dat_txn=dat_day
group by dat_day,nam_emp
order by dat_day
;
```

I am getting result as shown below

[This a result came after joining](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjiSV.png)

but where date is not available in dat_calender it is printing null value
but I want the name of employee with 0 value for that date even if employees has not done any task (absent/leave on that day)
And each employee start  date must be date in emp_task table and should be in range table.

For example

Mike has worked 25-Jan-2017 as per the above table then his start date will be 25-Jan only and remaing 6 days will be zero.
Like wise Manuel staring date is 29-Jan then remaing 2 days will be zero.
Same way for all employees available in the given date range.

Comment: This is an incomplete question because you didn't actually show us any table data or structure, but rather you pasted links to external images.  Please edit your question and include the data as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the summed column you should be able to just do `nvl(sum(num_task),0)`

however, it's not clear what employee name you want to display. If you want to display a record for each employee for each date, then you could do something like

```
with emps as (select distinct nam_emp from emp_task
              inner join dat_calendar on dat_txn=dat_day)
select e.nam_emp, c.dat_day, nvl(sum(et.num_task),0) tasks
from dat_calender c
cross join emps e
left join emp_task et on et.dat_txn = c.dat_day and et.nam_emp = e.nam_emp
group by c.dat_day, e.nam_emp
order by c.dat_day ;
```

Comment: Using an emps table would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Create min date and Join with above group with exist clause.